# Plotting Bestfit line Stocks

Tags: matplotlib, pandas, plot, line, regression

So far my class will get stock historical data from yahoo based on what stock ticker user inputs and how many days back they wish to see the historical data for.

I would like to add a best fit line(or linear regression line im still REALLY new to all this) that would add a line that would show the trend of the stock.

Any help would be appreciated or links would be great :)

```
#import modules
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from datetime import date, timedelta

class stockGraph():
    #sets up what to graph
    def __init__(self, stock, goback):
        self.goback = goback
        self.stock = stock
        #subtracts amount user inputted to get how far back to get data
        self.d = date.today() - timedelta(days = self.goback)
        #uses pandas io Datareader to get historical stock daya from yahoo
        self.df_stock = DataReader(self.stock, 'yahoo', self.d)

        #shows top 5 of the datafram values
        print self.df_stock.head()

    def dispGraph(self):
        #plots df_stock 'Close' is Y axis and X axis is the index in this case Date
        self.df_stock['Close'].plot()
        #rotates label and makes the graph a more readable
        plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
        plt.tight_layout()
        #shows graph
        plt.show()
```

Comment: scipy and numpy both have basic linear regression functions, here's scipy's: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html

Comment: How do I graph that line now? Again sorry im really new to matlab

Comment: Sounds like you need to break this question up into several parts. There are plenty of matplotlib and linear regression examples on SO and one of the more prominent pages in the matplotlib documentation is a gallery of images with the code to generate them http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html. Let us know if you have a question more specific.